# Why do I suddenly need signing key for PhoneGap Developer App?

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-build, hybrid-mobile-app, iphone-developer-program

I have been building on an hybrid app with PhoneGap for about a month. Have been using the PhoneGap Developer App for mobile all the time and have been working good all the time.

But suddenly, when I'm about to test the app today. It doesn't work. It just "Downloading" forever.

When I visit the build.phonegap.com website and watching my app build details there is an "Error" at iOS saying: `You must provide a signing key, first. Find out how to fix this.`.

I'm reading the text on the "[Find out how to fix this](http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap-build/signing/ios/)" link. But no info about why I suddenly need a signing key.

In order to get an signing key you have to have an "iPhone Development Certificate". And that costs. That's why I want to use PhoneGap. To be able to build and test the app before I buy the iPhone Developer Certificate.

Bottom line: **Why do I suddenly need signing key for PhoneGap Developer App?**

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you must have an iOS developer key to make signed .ipa file. You need it because without it you will not be able to deploy to any devices.

Comment: Why have I been able to do exactly the same thing for about a month without the key then? Notice, this is not about deploying it to be it's own app. This is about testing it on PhoneGap Developer App.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it now.

First of all: PhoneGap Developer App has nothing to do with PhoneGap Build. So that was two separate problem.

What caused the problem was something got wrong after I upgraded to latest Beta version.

**Solution:** When I downgraded to latest stable version, everything started working again.